# Добавить библиотеку в проект Node.js Express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webstorm, node-modules

Пытаюсь освоить WebStorm. Создал проект Node.js Express App.

Хочу добавить библиотеку.

Установил ее: `$ npm install vsvg-paths`

Я как понимаю, нужно в app.js ее подключить. Пытаюсь сделать это так:

`var vsvg_paths = require("vsvg-paths");`

`app.use(vsvg_paths.decode());`

Но мне тактично сообщают, что я делаю, что-то не так (говорит, что decode() не является функцией или просто ошибка подключения библиотеки, если укажу decode не как функцию).

Подскажите, как правильно подключить библиотеку или где почитать об этом?

Вот сама библиотека https://github.com/jcblw/vsvg-paths

Comment: А что вы пытаетесь получить вызовом `app.use(vsvg_paths.decode());`?

Comment: Я и пытаюсь понять вообще структуру проекта. Возможно я вообще все не так понял, как подключаются библиотеки. Поэтому и прошу показать на примере этой библиотеки, как это сделать правильно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подключаете вы её правильно. Непонятно, как вы её хотите использовать и где. В ответе Ares God всё верно, я перепроверил.

Проделанные действия:

- Создал проект Node.js Express App (версия *WS* 2017.1.1, версия приложения, созданного *express-generator* - 4.15.5)
- В файле **app.js** добавил код Ares God:

```js
// этот импорт вверху файла, до инициализации приложения
var paths = require( 'vsvg-paths' );

// этот код после импортов
var path = 'M0 0 L10 10 l1 1';
var data = paths.decode(path);
console.log('data:', data);
```

- Код вывел в консоль результат: `Data: [ { x: 0, y: 0, rel: false }, { x: 10, y: 10, rel: false }, { x: 1, y: 1, rel: true } ]`

Запускал через меню **Run -> Run...** В появившемся окошке выбрал **app.js**

Если вы хотели использовать эту библиотеку на клиенте, то вам нужно добавить её в папку */public/javascript/vsvg-paths* и импортировать в index.html

```html
<script src="public/javascripts/vsvg-paths/decode.js"></script>
```

Comment: хмм..то есть вся логика выполнения библиотеки должна быть в app.js? Если это так, то это не верно или я не так понял вас.Я думал, что подключив библиотеку в app.js (мне нужна функция decode и encode), то я могу юзать их в других скриптах, например в /public/js/script.js...

Comment: Не обязательно, просто так проще всего проверить. Тот же код можно добавить **в любой роут или контроллер** _(меня могут поправить более опытные коллеги, если вдруг это плохая практика)_, но для запуска этого кода нужно будет каждый раз проделать больше действий

Comment: В _/public/js/script.js_ хранится клиентский код, то есть то, что будет передано в браузер. Если вам надо использовать эту библиотеку на клиенте (в браузере), тогда вам совершенно иначе нужно его импортировать.

Answer (score 3):

[Там](https://github.com/jcblw/vsvg-paths) же все написано:

```
var paths = require( 'vsvg-paths' );

var path = 'M0 0 L10 10 l1 1';
var data = paths.decode(path);
```

Comment: Так не работает, то есть я не могу сделать так, чтобы в каком-нибудь скрипте `var paths = require( 'vsvg-paths' );` это сработало (reauire not defined), нужно его добавить в проект как-то, и я не знаю как это делается в Nodejs Express App

Comment: где вы видите `require not defined` - в редакторе или в консоли. при запуске приложения? В первом случае проблема решается подключением **Node.js Core** библиотеки (**File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and NPM**). Во втором - проблема в том, как вы запускаете код (возможно, вы его в браузере(?) выполнять пытаетесь?)

Comment: Я же юзаю WebStrom - запускаю www.js и мне сообщают, чтобы я перешел на localhost:[номер порта]